# Compute $P(Y|X_1)$ when $P(X_1)$ and $P(X_1|X_2)$ are given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Consider two Normal distributions$$
\begin{align}
P(X_1)&=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)=\epsilon\sigma\\
P(X_1|X_2)&=\mathcal N(f(x_2),\sigma^2)=f(x_2)+\epsilon \sigma
\end{align}
$$where $\epsilon\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

Now, I have another Normal distribution that is conditioned on $X_1$:$$
P(Y|X_1)=\mathcal N(g(x_1),\sigma^2)
$$
My question is, which parameterization of $X_1$ do I sample to compute $Y|X_1$ ? The first or second ? Do I need further contexts for $P(Y|X_1)$ or are the given informations sufficient?

I am studying denoising diffusion models and this problem arises in one of its derivation.

Comment: The expression $P(X_1)$ does not make sense. Please be careful with notation.

Comment: It does make sense, albeit non standard. It can be viewed as a map $P:\mathcal H\to \mathcal P$ where $H$ is some collection of random variables and $\mathcal P$ is some collection of Borel probability measures on the real line.

Comment: I may think that $P(X)$ means Fermat's theorem, but  it means nonsense.

Comment: @kludg agree — looks more like OP is defining distribution vs a probability — I’ve been guilty of that too as informal notation but I agree it’s technically nonsense

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ only depends on $X_1$ why would you use $X_2$ to indirectly calculate $Y$?

It depends on what you expect to know -- do you even know $X_1$ or are you only given $X_2$? And is $X_2$ fixed or will vary between time periods?

If you only will have direct access to $X_2$ then you have to use the second option. If you have $X_1$ then there is no reason not to use $X_1$ directly.

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite confused by the last statement. If I only have access to $X_2$ then the second one is used. However, if I have both access, is it still (valid) to use the second option ? Your first statement might imply that it is possible to use both with the first one being more suitable

Comment: @wdviolet had a typo in second paragraph— missing “not”.  The only reason I’d use the second option is if I didn’t know $X_1$ since Y only depends on $X_1$ unless  I’ve totally misunderstood your notation